# conditional aggregation on two different groups in SQL

Tags: sql

Here is my data

```
COUNTYID POLLUTANT TYPE EMISSION
1        A         1  
1        A         2
1        B         1
1        B         2
2        A         1
2        A         2  
2        B         1 
2        B         2
3        A         1
3        A         2
3        B         1 
3        B         2
```

if I do

```
SELECT sum(EMISSION) from table where POLLUTANT = 'A' group by COUNTYID;
```

I would get pollution from Polutant 'A'. how can I write a query to get following data:

column 1 with sum of A, column 2 with sum of B, column 3 with sum of A and B?

Thank you

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation. But what's the expected result if pollutant D suddenly shows up?

Comment: It is disorienting that you are trying to sum `emission` which has no values. Or are you trying to count rows?

Comment: When your assignment gets a database you might get an answer.  Show desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case for filter the value you need

```
  select COUNTYID, sum(case when POLLUTANT='A'then EMISSION else 0 END)  tot_a
   , sum(case when POLLUTANT='B'then EMISSION else 0 END)  tot_b
   , sum(EMISSION)  tot_a_b
  from my_table 
  group by COUNTYID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  This moves the filtering conditions from the `where` clause to the `sum()`s:

```
select countyid,
       sum(case when emission = 'A' then emission else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when emission = 'B' then emission else 0 end) as B,
       sum(emission) as total
from t
group by countyid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give some idea. We can use pivot table for answer your question

```
SELECT * from  dbo.[Table_1]
PIVOT
(Sum([type_emmssion]) for [polutant] in ([A], [B]) ) as PivotTable
 group by  [CountryId]  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use case statemet:

```
SELECT 
 SUM( CASE WHEN POLLUTANT = 'A' THEN EMISSION ELSE 0 END) AS A_EMISSION
 SUM( CASE WHEN POLLUTANT = 'B' THEN EMISSION ELSE 0 END) AS B_EMISSION
 SUM(EMISSION) AS total_emission
FROM table 
GROUP BY COUNTYID;
```